# field mapping of custom fields for lead conversion

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

While doing a lead conversion using Database.LeadConvert When we do the convert does it also convert the custom fields set using the Lead Custom Field Mapping which is set on the UI?

I would think it should but couldnt find anything on it to confirm.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any custom field mappings that you specify using the Map Lead Fields button will be copied across to Account / Contact / Opportunity during Lead Conversion (even if custom), as specified in your mapping.

http://na8.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_mapleads.htm

Answer (score -2):

yaa, definately custom fields are also mapped..before that you map custom fields in lead to -->Account or Contact or opportunity Custom fields.Than surely you can get it.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Can you provide clear instructions on what you're suggesting?

Comment: Are you suggesting that i need to map the custom fields of Leads to Accounts, Leads to contact and lead to contact in the UI first from the MapLead fields button underLead Custom Fields & Relationships. setup->customize->Leads->fields